# File.createNewFile avoid Inappropriate blocking method call in coroutine

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have a coroutine that make a couple calls to functions that do file IO to save and process a file stream coming from a server.

```
private suspend fun fetchFile(fileId: String) {
   val response = service.getFile(fileId)
   if (response.isSuccessful) {
      val destination = File("my_directory", "image.png")
      destination.createNewFile()

      ...
   }
}
```

However createNewFile complains

```
"Inappropriate blocking method call"
```

Its a private method and the parent method in the class ensures this is on the IO dispatcher:

```
suspend fun syncFile(fileId: String) = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
   fetchFile(fileId)
}
```

Based on what I have read I am OK, as I am within the IO context.  However the more I read, the more I find that its still not great to call blocking functions in a coroutine.  And in fact most libraries are moving to provide suspending functions for all IO operations.  EG, if you look above the call *service.getFile(fileId)* is a retrofit call that takes advantage of retrofits suspend implementation.

That leads me to the question, is there really no non-blocking kotlin API for java.io.File operations like createNewFile()? Assuming there is not since I cannot find one, how would I "wrap" or provide a utility to functions like this to make them truly non blocking?

FWIW, I have seen plenty of answers that just lead to "hiding" the warning, which is not really what I want to do.  IE, putting the offending code in a small non suspending function and calling that function, or wrapping in *runCatching { ... }*, both of which just make the warning hidden to inspection.

**EDIT:**
wrapping in *withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { ... }* does not help.

[image]

Comment: I think the warning will go away if you move `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` inside `fetchFile`. I think File-IO eventually will be implemented in the kotlinx-io library. See here: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx-io#platform

Comment: See edit, wrapping in withContext(...), does not make the warning go away.  This is also not necessary as I am already wrapped.  Looks like there are some plans for File I/O, but in a very limited fashion.  Weird cause file IO is a pretty common use case.  Question still remains, if kotlin is late to the game on providing what I need, what is the proper way, if possible, to write my own non blocking utility.

Comment: Bummer, the link you posted has not had any movement in over 2 years.  Don't think waiting on kotlin devs to provide this is a good idea.

Comment: Yeah. Anyway, using `Dispatchers.IO` is the appropriate way to handle this. The warning seems to be a bit buggy, so I think it's ok to suppress it when you know you have handled it correctly. `Dispatchers.IO` is designed to handle blocking calls like this: https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-dispatchers/-i-o.html

Comment: @marstran I get that, and agreed.  I guess better than writing my own, most likely, buggy implementation. Still just amazed that koltin has ignored File IO for so long.

Comment: I think that your real problem is a broken Lint check. Your call is not inappropriate, as the primary use case of a coroutine is to execute blocking calls on a background thread (via a suitable dispatcher).

Comment: It is convention to handle setting the appropriate dispatcher internally in the function rather than relying on the caller to do it correctly. `suspend` advertises that a function can be called from any dispatcher and won't block. But even when you do it internally, the lint has false positives.

Comment: Yes, you are correct we should try to avoid blocking threads, even with `Dispatchers.IO`. If there are non-blocking alternatives, they're always better. The problem is: there aren't such alternatives. Kotlin can't provide non-blocking file IO, because JVM does not provide it. And JVM does not provide it, because AFAIK even operating systems does not provide it. I believe we have non-blocking operations for sockets, but not for files. Even if we use `AsynchronousChannel` it just delegates to IO threads, so it does the same as `Dispatchers.IO`. Please correct me if I'm entirely wrong.

Comment: Having said that, I still miss some tools for handling Java IO with coroutines. There are libs like okio, also `ktor-io` submodule of Ktor is interesting, but I believe there is nothing for dealing with Java APIs directly. I'm considering writing something like this.

Comment: @broot, thanks that is extremely helpful!